# How do you concatenate strings and integers in C++?

Tags: c++, string, type-conversion

I am trying to concatenate strings and integers as follows:

```
#include "Truck.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Truck::Truck (string n, string m, int y)
{
    name = n;
    model = m;
    year = y;
    miles = 0;
}

string Truck :: toString()
{

    string truckString =  "Manufacturer's Name: " + name + ", Model Name: " + model + ", Model Year: " + year ", Miles: " + miles;
    return truckString;
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
error: invalid operands to binary expression ('basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >'
      and 'int')
        string truckString =  "Manufacturer's Name: " + name + ", Model Name: " + model + ", Model Year: " + year ", Miles...
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong? I am new to C++.

Comment: Use `std::to_string` or a sting stream.

Comment: @chris, I tried that I get this error: error: no member named 'to_string' in namespace 'std'

Comment: I was running into this problem earlier today and found out that depending on your compiler set up, you might not have access to `to_string` for some reason. Take a look at stringstreams for the conversion from `int` to `string`: http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/D9j2Nwbp/

Comment: @user1471980, It's C++11 and in `<string>`. Older versions of GCC could have problems with it as well.

Comment: You don't (or shouldn't) concatenate strings and integers.  You can concatenate strings with other strings, and some of those strings may be the character representation of integers, but they are not integers.  Many languages (including Java and C++) help you with this by implicitly converting integers into their string representations when certain operators are used.

Comment: boost::lexical_cast is also useful for this purpose

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In C++03, as other people have mentioned, you can use the `ostringstream` type, defined in `<sstream>`:

```
std::ostringstream stream;
stream << "Mixed data, like this int: " << 137;
std::string result = stream.str();
```

In C++11, you can use the `std::to_string` function, which is conveniently declared in `<string>`:

```
std::string result = "Adding things is this much fun: " + std::to_string(137);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

```
std::stringstream s;
s << "Manufacturer's Name: " << name
  << ", Model Name: " << model
  << ", Model Year: " << year
  << ", Miles: " << miles;

s.str();
```

Comment: Please make sure your code is indented with four spaces, or press CTRL+K to indent it automatically. Otherwise, it'll be interpreted as plain text. See [formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream):

```
std::string name, model;
int year, miles;
...
std::ostringstream os;
os << "Manufacturer's Name: " << name << 
      ", Model Name: " << model <<
      ", Model Year: " << year <<
      ", Miles: " << miles;
std::cout << os.str();               // <-- .str() to obtain a std::string object
```